# Integration of Lucene.NET / SOLR With ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT(ASPDNSF)

Tags: lucene.net, solrnet, aspdotnetstorefront

I need to build Lucene.NET or SOLR with ASPDNSF, With XMLPACKAGES. So any one of you have any idea to do so ? An idea can help me to meet my needs.

Also is there any other way - which helps to improve the searching of 200k+ products on my application  ?

Thank You,
dL

Answer (score 0):

FULL DISCLOSURE: We are the maker of [SmartSearch, Search for AspDotNetStorefront](http://store.morrisonconsulting.com/p-5-moco-smart-search-for-aspdotnetstorefront.aspx).

Todate I have not come across a marketed Solr solution for AspDotNetStorefront. We started out heading down that path in 2007 and in the end didn't want to have to have the mixed (apache, iis) environments and turned to Lucene.net to to write our own IR for AspDotNetStorefront. We needed to be able to search hundreds of thousands of products. We have since grown our solution well beyond what lucene.net can alone provide.

As far as managing that many products there are a handful of information retrieval options out there that work with storefront. Here are a handful saving the best for last ;)

SERVICES:

Nextopia http://nextopia.com/ecommerce-site-search-aspdotnetstorefront.html

SLI Systems http://www.sli-systems.com/solutions/site-search

I know services can run around $1,000 per year for search results only, if you want it to power your navigation it goes 10 fold in price per year for lower volume sites.

HOST YOUR OWN: aspdotnetstorefront addons.

Compunix xSearch http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-961-xsearch-extreme-search-for-aspdotnetstorefront.aspx

Morrison Consulting [Smart Search for AspDotNetStorefront](http://store.morrisonconsulting.com/p-5-moco-smart-search-for-aspdotnetstorefront.aspx) http://store.morrisonconsulting.com/p-5-moco-smart-search-for-aspdotnetstorefront.aspx

Smart Search is much more than just search, we power the entire browsing experience with it as AspDotNetStorefront itself starts slowing down beyond 100k products.

Comment: Okay, But i want to create my own functionality of Advanced Searching. :)